# Export wizard application in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, executable-jar, wizard

I did a sample application mentioned in this  link using Netbeans Wizard template https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-wizard.html

But how do I export as executable jar. I just want to execute the project independently with out IDE. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find it in the tutorial that you point to but in order to share your newly created Netbeans plugin you need to export it as a binary NetBeans Module or `.nbm` file. Right click on your project and select Create NBM. Check this old tutorial here: http://docs.huihoo.com/netbeans/6.0/kb/60/platform/nbm-google.html

For Netbeans 8.0: When the file is created you can then go Tools->Plugins ,  downloaded tab and then click add plugins

[image: add plugins]

**EDIT (based on your comments)**

The tuturial you point to guides you to build a custom Netbeans module (in this case a Wizard). The module is packaged as a .nbm file which you can then distribute it so that it can be installed to any Netbeans IDE.

As it turns out you need something like a "Java swing wizard" application. By searching google you can find some results that fit your needs (these are from the first google results):

- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/wizard-136789.html
- https://code.google.com/p/cjwizard/
- http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077850/java-se/open-source-java-projects-the-wizard-api.html
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/jwf/
- Similar question (maybe you can post a comment asking for details there):
  https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/132723/is-there-a-java-library-to-create-assisted-wizard-flow-into-your-desktop-applica

Hope I am not leading you to the wrong way but another thing you can also have a look at, (haven't checked it myself but you might find it useful) is how to create OSGI modules and the posibility of converting Netbeans modules to OSGI modules. 
Look here: http://wiki.netbeans.org/OSGiAndNetBeans.

Comment: Hi @user153089 is that what you want?

Comment: No that is not what I want. i want to export wizard as an executable jar.  once I click on jar the wizard should open.

Comment: I think answer is correct but What I am supposed to do is not what I want. sorry. it is my fault.

Comment: Hi @zlinks thanks very much for information. I will go through it. you are guiding me in right direction.