# Can NBM (NetBeans Module) application run as standalone java application

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

This question might be very dumb question but I am completely new to NBM application.

I created a NBM application in net beans. I really liked creating wizard app in netbeans, it is very handy and easy to build.

Can I run NBM application as standalone wizard application? like a executable jar app.

If not, is there any framework that i use to build swings wizard application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Export wizard application in netbeans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23122292/export-wizard-application-in-netbeans)

Comment: I posted this question too. but I want to know if it is possible to export nbm files.

Answer (score 0):

Please loot at this forum for solution. We cannot make NBM project as standalone java application.

http://forums.netbeans.org/viewtopic.php?p=157046#157046